# Reversing each word in a sentence

Tags: c, strings

Below code reverse a word  given by user input  example.

**input : This is code Review**

**output : siht si edoc weiveR**

### steps

step 1: check for whitespace if found set the start and end position and 
        pass to **reverseword**

step 2: check for null terminator  and set start and end position pass to **reverseword**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 100
#define SPACE 1
#define NEXT 1
#define MIN_CHAR 1
void  reverseword(int start,int end,char *input)
{
        char temp;
        int i;
        while(end > start)
        {
                temp=input[start];
                input[start]=input[end];
                input[end]= temp;
                start++;
                end--;
        }
}

int main()
{
        char input[MAX];
        scanf("%[^\n]",input);
        int pos;
        int start=0,end=0;
        for(pos=0 ; input[pos] ; ++pos)
        {
                if(isspace(input[pos]) && pos>MIN_CHAR) // case when space is found
                {
                        end = pos-SPACE;
                        reverseword(start,end,input);
                        start= pos+SPACE;
                }
                if(input[pos+NEXT]=='\0' && pos>MIN_CHAR) // case for last world
                {
                        end =pos;
                        reverseword(start,end,input);
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Enable warnings**

The `-Wall` on GCC leads to:

```
reverse.c:10:13: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

**Do not repeat yourself**

You check `pos > MIN_CHAR` in two places. This could be done only once:

```
    if (pos > MIN_CHAR)
    {
        if(isspace(input[pos])) // case when space is found
        {
            end = pos-SPACE;
            reverseword(start,end,input);
            start= pos+SPACE;
        }
        if(input[pos+NEXT]=='\0') // case for last world
        {
            end =pos;
            reverseword(start,end,input);
        }
    }
```

**Be consistent in your code style**

The code style seems a bit inconsistent. For instance, sometimes you have whitespaces before "=", sometimes after, sometimes both, sometimes none... You'll find various coding styles online and different tools to check you code compliancy.

**Declare variables in smallest possible scope**

I find it a good habit to define variable in the smallest scope in order to make things easier to track. In your case, `temp` could be declared inside the loop.

**Getting rid of the your `#define`-d values**

All your values (except for `MAX`) could be removed because the link between the name and the value is hard to understand at first.:w

So far, I've got:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100

void reverseword(int start, int end, char *input)
{
    while (end > start)
    {
        char temp = input[start];
        input[start] = input[end];
        input[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Updated for testing purposes
    //        char input[MAX];
    //        scanf("%[^\n]",input);
    char * original = "this is code review";
    char * input = strdup(original);
    printf("%s\n", input);
    int pos;
    int start = 0;
    for (pos = 0 ; input[pos] ; ++pos)
    {
        if (pos > 1)
        {
            if (isspace(input[pos])) // case when space is found
            {
                int end = pos-1;
                reverseword(start, end, input);
                start = pos + 1;
            }
            if (input[pos+1] == '\0') // case for last world
            {
                int end = pos;
                reverseword(start, end, input);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", input);
}
```

**Typo: You meant "word", not "world"**

Not much to add here.

**Handle the last word at the end**

You can handle the final case the end. Then you can merge the condition check togetherin the loop.

**Bug found**

We have the following behaviors:

- "a this is code review" -> "siht a si edoc weiver"
- " a this is code review" -> "a  siht si edoc weiver"

*I have to go, I'll try to continue asap.*

Comment: Why don't you use a headline (`# example`) instead of **bold** text?

Comment: Oops, no specific reason :-(

Answer (score 2):

Various problems exists with `scanf("%[^\n]",input);`

1. It can over-fill leading to UB.
2. If the first character is a `'\n'`, `input[]` remains un-assigned leading to UB and `'\n'` still in `stdin`.
3. A rare input error is not detected leading to subsequent UB.
4. On typical input, `'\n'` remains in `stdin`, which could make a difference with a larger program.

Use `fgets()`

```
char input[MAX + 1];
if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';  // lop off potential \n
```

---

When `ch < 0` `is....(ch)` is *undefined behavior*.  Best to make `unsigned char`.

```
// if(isspace(input[pos]) && ....
if(isspace((unsigned char) input[pos]) && ....
```

---

With the context of OP's code with small strings, `reverseword()` using `int` is not a problem.  For maximal functionality, C best uses `size_t` for array indexing and so should `reverseword()`.  Recommend to define variables closer to where they are needed.  `int i;` is superfluous.

```
void reverseword(size_t start, size_t end, char *input) {
  while(end > start) {
    char temp = input[start];
    input[start] = input[end];
    input[end] = temp;
    start++;
    end--;
  }
}
```

---

Inconsistent indentation implies OP is not using an auto-formatter to maintain a consistent style.  Life is too short for manually maintaining the format.  Use a programing environment that has an auto formatter and use it.